# Allow neo4j to match the same node under multiple different names

Tags: neo4j, erlang, cypher

I'm working on a project (to be exact, [RefactorErl](http://plc.inf.elte.hu/erlang/)), where we are storing the syntactic trees and semantic graphs of erlang programs to do refactorings and other sorts of analysis, transformations and queries on them. These were previously stored in and benchmarked against different key-value stores, relational and document based databases, but I decided to try and implement a neo4j backend, as it seemed suitable for path like queries such as "list all the variables of the functions that are in a module called `xyz`" and similar actions.

I wrote a neo4j wrapper library ([neo4j_driver](https://github.com/Isti115/neo4j_driver)) as the older ones I've found were using an API that's now being deprecated and got to a point where it's almost working with the appropriate filters and everything, but one thing I just cannot solve is the lack of ability to match the same node under multiple names in a query. This seems necessary, as there are times when searching backwards through relations is unavoidable. For example when the program (for example because it is needed for a refactoring) tries to search for all the variables that are in the same function as let's say a given `X` (identified by giving the parameter `fromId`), it translates that to Cypher and gives something like this:

```
MATCH (from:var)<-[edge1:vardef]-(node1)-[edge2:vardef]->(node2) WHERE id(from) = $fromId RETURN labels(node2), id(node2) ORDER BY edge1.orderId, edge2.orderId"
```

*(Here `orderId` is the lexical order of the elements in the file.)*

The problem is that this only gives the variables inside the function that contains `X` **other than `X` itself**, as it would need to match under the names *"from"* and *"node2"* at the same time. Is there a way to construct such a query that avoids this problem? I know that I could try to avoid naming the nodes sequentially and filter with curly braces inside the node, but that way I could only do exact matches, not for example ranges.

ps.: The current code that I wrote for translating the path queries looks like this, please tell me if it is horrible as I feel like there could be better ways to do this:

```
filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, empty_filter) -> "";
filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, Filter) ->
    case Filter of
        {'not', InnerFilter} ->
            "NOT (" ++ filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, InnerFilter) ++ ")";
        {LeftFilter, 'and', RightFilter} ->
            "((" ++ filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, LeftFilter) ++
            ") AND (" ++ filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, RightFilter) ++ "))";
        {LeftFilter, 'or', RightFilter} ->
            "((" ++ filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, LeftFilter) ++
            ") OR (" ++ filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, RightFilter) ++ "))";
        {Property, '==', Value} ->
            NodeName ++ "." ++ to_str(Property) ++ " = '" ++ to_str(Value) ++ "'";
        {Property, '/=', Value} ->
            NodeName ++ "." ++ to_str(Property) ++ " <> '" ++ to_str(Value) ++ "'";
        {Property, '<', Value} ->
            NodeName ++ "." ++ to_str(Property) ++ " < '" ++ to_str(Value) ++ "'";
        {Property, '>', Value} ->
            NodeName ++ "." ++ to_str(Property) ++ " > '" ++ to_str(Value) ++ "'";
        {Property, '<=', Value} ->
            NodeName ++ "." ++ to_str(Property) ++ " <= '" ++ to_str(Value) ++ "'";
        {Property, '>=', Value} ->
            NodeName ++ "." ++ to_str(Property) ++ " >= '" ++ to_str(Value) ++ "'";
        % last ->
        %     EdgeName ++ ".orderId = " ++ to_str(get_last_id());
        Id when is_integer(Id) ->
            EdgeName ++ ".orderId = " ++ to_str(Id);
        Other -> own_debug("Unknown filter", [Filter]), ""
    end.

path_element_to_query_part({Id, {Tag, Direction, Filter}}) ->
    NodeName = "node" ++ to_str(Id),
    EdgeName = "edge" ++ to_str(Id),

    Edge = "[" ++ EdgeName ++ ":" ++ to_str(Tag) ++ "]",

    MatchClauseElement =
        case Direction of
            back -> "<-" ++ Edge ++ "-";
            fwd -> "-" ++ Edge ++ "->"
        end ++ "(" ++ NodeName ++ ")",

    WhereClauseElement = filter_to_where_clause_element(NodeName, EdgeName, Filter),

    OrderByClauseElement = EdgeName ++ ".orderId",

    { MatchClauseElement, WhereClauseElement, OrderByClauseElement }.

path(Node, Path) ->
    {?NODETAG, Class, Id} = Node,

    NormalizedIndexedPath = lists:zip(
        lists:seq(1, length(Path)),
        lists:map(fun(PE) -> normalize_path_element(PE) end, Path)
    ),

    QueryPathElements = lists:map(
        fun(IndexedPathElement) ->
            path_element_to_query_part(IndexedPathElement)
        end,
        NormalizedIndexedPath
    ),

    { MatchClauseElements, WhereClauseElements, OrderByClauseElements } = {
        lists:map(
            fun(QueryPathElement) -> element(1, QueryPathElement) end,
            QueryPathElements
        ),
        lists:map(
            fun(QueryPathElement) -> element(2, QueryPathElement) end,
            QueryPathElements
        ),
        lists:map(
            fun(QueryPathElement) -> element(3, QueryPathElement) end,
            QueryPathElements
        )
    },

    JoinedMatchClause = string:join(MatchClauseElements, ""),
    LastNodeName = "node" ++ to_str(length(Path)),

    JoinedWhereClause = string:join(
        lists:filter(
            fun(WhereClauseElement) -> WhereClauseElement /= "" end,
            ["id(from) = $fromId" | WhereClauseElements]
        ),
        " AND "
    ),

    JoinedOrderByClause = string:join(OrderByClauseElements, ", "),

    Statements = [
        [
            { statement,
                "MATCH (from:" ++ to_str(Class) ++ ")" ++
                JoinedMatchClause ++
                " WHERE " ++ JoinedWhereClause ++
                " RETURN labels(" ++ LastNodeName ++ "), id(" ++ LastNodeName ++ ")" ++
                " ORDER BY " ++ JoinedOrderByClause
            },
            { parameters, [
                { "fromId", Id }
            ] }
        ]
    ],
    Result = run_cypher_query(Statements),
    MatchedNodes = lists:map(fun (Row) ->
        [[TargetClass], TargetId] = Row,
        {?NODETAG, parse(TargetClass), TargetId}
    end, get_rows(Result)),
    { ok, MatchedNodes }.
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to split your single `MATCH` clause into comma-separated clauses or multiple `MATCH` clauses?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As far as I can see from reading a bit online, comma-separated clauses wouldn't solve this, because they still share the same namespace, just allow branching. Multiple `MATCH` clauses could work, but then I would need to connect them manually to link the chain together. Wouldn't that destroy their performance?

Comment: Multiple `MATCH` clauses do create the cross product, I believe, but I generally find it easier to optimize the query (and/or database design) after I have the correct results.